# how to add new auto renewable in-app purchase while app in live

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

need some help.
Would like to know that,  is possible to add new in-app purchase to my live app.if so how to submit that in-app purchse to review. help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Go to your iTunes connect -> my apps -> select your app -> tap on features -> you should see a list called In-App purchases -> click + and add new IAP, select the specific subscription group if you have any. Provide all meta data and click submit for review. As simple as it gets

Comment: You should read it first https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267